# Android Dropbox Sync Api Example with Login ID and Password from Code

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm creating an app which will upload pictures from a particular folder of the SDCard.

Now using the dropbox feature I want to upload it. But I don't want my user to get the Login Screen.

What I want is the Code will have a Dropbox ID and Password written and the Api should use that an proceed.

I have gone through Dropbox Developer Blog. But I'm kinda a newbie in it. Hence I have no idea what it really wants me to do with oAuth. 
Any example to other sites will work. Or some sought of tutorial.

If its not possible then I need to rethink my process flow.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.
The user always has to accept that his account will be linked with your app.
The App ID is just required in to link the account with the right app.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to that.
but there is not a big Deal if your user getting this login page ones. you can able to save that linked account info in perf.